# Dart and third party libs

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, dart, marionette

I have a few projects written on Typescript.

TS has a declaration files (d.ts) to declare non-ts libs. How it's works in Dart?

Dart looks very cool but I'd like to use Backbone and Marionette in my project.

Is there opportunity to rewrite projects at Dart or use Dart in next project using Marionette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some attempts or plans to support that better but currently I guess this isn't too easy.

- `dart:js` provides support to call between Dart and JS but this probably won't work with `d.ts`. You'd need to rebuild d.ts for `dart:js`.
  Support for `d.ts` seems to be work in progress and a first version should become available in the not too far future https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23423
- The dev_compiler team is working on generating TypeScript output from Dart code https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler/issues/397. I don't know about the status. Seems to be farther away.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at package:js, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js and see the ChartJS example there. Angular has a ts2dart compiler, but I don't know if that would actually convert the d.ts files or if you'd need to do that by hand. It doesn't seem like it would be too difficult to turn d.ts definitions into package:js definitions.